# Why I am having syntax error when I am using multilines quote?

Tags: python

Here's the code:

```
'''

file_path = (r'C:\Users\Luka\Desktop\Pyhton exercises\pi_digits.txt')

with open(file_path) as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()
    print(contents)
    #print(contents.rstrip()) # rstrip should remove blank space at the end


'''

filename = ("prova.txt")

with open(filename) as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        print(line)
```

Comment: How? I mentioned that i'm getting an error because of the multilines quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `file_path` variable between triple quotes. `C:\` starts an eight-character Unicode escape. In your code, the escape is followed by the character `U`, which is invalid.

Double up your backslashes to escape them, e.g.:

```
"""
file_path = (r'C:\\Users\\Luka\\Desktop\\Pyhton exercises\\pi_digits.txt')

with open(file_path) as file_object: contents = file_object.read() print(contents) #print(contents.rstrip()) # rstrip should remove blank space at the end

"""

filename = "prova.txt"
```

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw can you explain why with double \\ I don't get the error?

Comment: Stop telling people to "paste into an IDE". You need to explain your answer _here_. See [answer]. (I now see that you actually do that at the end, but it's not very clear. _Start_ by explaining the problem and solution. Don't start with code to "paste".)

Comment: @Kovacic95 if it does not show an error please award my response as a valid one? :) It is giving error because you are writing directory with 1 slash. Slash is considered as an escape character. By placing 2 slashes you are telling that you do not want to escape any character.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for that, thought that my answer above is an enough explanation.